# Java проверка открытости UDP порта

Tags: java, udp

Не могу написать код, который проверяет открыт UDP порт или нет. Мне нужно, чтобы мой код обрабатывал ICMP пакеты от системы о том, что порт недоступен. В документации написано, что connect() должен возвращать PortUnreachableException, если возвращается ICMP пакет. Но я не смог ни разу поймать это исключение. В WireShark ICMP пакеты обрабатываются корректно. Может кто-нибудь написать пример, когда вылезает исключение PortUnreachableException о недоступности UDP порта.

```
try {
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    socket.connect(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(), 5);
    String message = "Hello";
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), message.length(), socket.getInetAddress(), socket.getPort());
    socket.send(packet);
    socket.send(packet);
    socket.send(packet);
}catch (PortUnreachableException e) {
    System.out.println("PortUnreachable"); //Это исключение не выбрасывается
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: connect не возвращает данное исключение.  PortUnreachableException выбрасывает метод send

Comment: У меня вопрос, вы хотите принимать пакеты, или все таки отправлять? Потому что фраза "код обрабатывал ICMP пакеты от системы" она о приеме, а ваш код - он про отправку

Comment: send отправляет пакет в сеть и не думает ни о каком ответе. сделайте сокет неблокирующим и после пары send сделайте recv. только имейте ввиду, что надо выждать некоторый таймаут, к моменту как завершится вызов send и начнется recv ответ просто физически вернуться еще не успеет, к этому времени даже отправленный пакет дойти до получателя не успеет. И кстати, может я ошибаюсь и следующий send то же способен вернуть ошибку, но ответа к его моменту еще нет ...

Comment: Ну есть такая программа пинг.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin то что connect не выбрасывает исключение это логично. Но исключение должен выбрасывать send (как я понял из документации). Однако исключение не выбрасывается. По поводу отправки сообщения: насколько я знаю, после отправки сообщения на закрытый порт, он должен (но не обязан) отправлять ICMP пакет с сообщением о недостижимости порта. Я никак не могу поймать это сообщение. Возможно я не там копаю, потому что мне просто нужно проверить открыть UDP порт или нет. Если есть способ попроще, буду рад, если вы расскажете.

Comment: @RomanC Не совсем понимаю как мне может помочь Ping. Он же просто отправляет ICMP пакеты повышая TTL.

Comment: @Mike не совсем понял как это прописать в коде. Всё что я пробую либо вызывает исключение на любом порте, либо не вызывает никогда. Не могли бы вы привести пример кода?

Comment: ну самое простое наверно сделать какую нибудь задержку. у вас есть что то типа sleep() ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение. Работает только в том случае, если закрытый порт на который отправляется пакет возвращает ICMP пакет.

```
try {
    DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    byte[] pingData = "PING".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    InetAddress hostAdress = InetAddress.getByName(hostName);
    datagramSocket.connect(hostAdress, port);
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(pingData, pingData.length, hostAdress, port);
    datagramSocket.send(sendPacket);
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[8];
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    datagramSocket.setSoTimeout(200);
    datagramSocket.receive(receivePacket);
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    return true;
} catch (IOException e) {
    return false;
}
return false;
```